# Save form data to MySQL DB - FLex + Java

Tags: java, mysql, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I need to connect my Flex front end to a Java backend. I need to save some form data to MySQL.

The FLex front end has 2 form fields namely Name and Age. When the user clicks on the button i need it to be saved in a MySQL DB.

Can someone help me. I am new to Flex.

Comment: I'm unclear how this question is different than the question you asked 7 hours ago?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134980/saving-form-fields-in-a-mysql-db-usinf-flex

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving form fields in a MySQL DB usinf Flex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134980/saving-form-fields-in-a-mysql-db-usinf-flex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlazeDS might be what you're looking for. Here's a nice 'getting started' article: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/blazeds_gettingstarted.html

I used it extensively up until about a year ago when it became apparent that HTML5 was going to eat Flex's lunch. It's a shame I left it, because it's nice stuff - very efficient data transfer compared to JSON or XML and it integrates nicely into Flashbuilder or Flexbuilder - whatever they're calling it now.

Comment: HTML5 actually should even feed on the same table with Flex.
It is like to eat on the same table with you dog. ( i am pointing HTML5 as the dog here ).
HTML5 main idea is to support the WEB2, not to be some kind of RIA for everything. Thus that lately some companies trying to deep your  pocket this way have nothing with it's base idea.